# highcharts how to override reset zoom button event

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to override the reset zoom button click event in highcharts? When I click the reset zoom button, I want the chart to display the specific interval using setExtremes instead of zooming out the whole chart.

Answer (score 1):

you can capture it in the `selection` property of your chart object. Just use the `setExtremes()`function with where you want to zoom, and a timeout of 0ms so that the graph's 'reset graph' function doesn't overwrite it.

```
chart: {
   events: {
      selection: function(event) {
         if (!event.xAxis) {
            setTimeout(function(){chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 5)}, 0);
         }
      }
    ...
  }
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rhavelka/M7cfm/64/

**edit:** but make sure that you want to zoom in on that specific interval and essentially hiding data from the user (unless you have a scrollbar on the graph like this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/scrollable-plotarea))

Answer (score 0):

You can **overwrite** default `Chart.prototype.showResetZoom` and provide your own logic in `zoomOut` function:

```
(function(H) {
  H.Chart.prototype.showResetZoom = function() {

    var chart = this,
        defaultOptions = H.defaultOptions,
      fireEvent = H.fireEvent,
      lang = defaultOptions.lang,
      btnOptions = chart.options.chart.resetZoomButton,
      theme = btnOptions.theme,
      states = theme.states,
      alignTo = btnOptions.relativeTo === 'chart' ? null : 'plotBox';

    function zoomOut() {
      //chart.zoomOut(); // default action
      chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(3, 7); // new action
    }

    fireEvent(this, 'beforeShowResetZoom', null, function() {
      chart.resetZoomButton = chart.renderer.button(
          lang.resetZoom,
          null,
          null,
          zoomOut,
          theme,
          states && states.hover
        )
        .attr({
          align: btnOptions.position.align,
          title: lang.resetZoomTitle
        })
        .addClass('highcharts-reset-zoom')
        .add()
        .align(btnOptions.position, false, alignTo);
    });
  }

})(Highcharts);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ay0t2e9f/

**Docs reference:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts